How do I disable a JFrame's specific window control button in Java?
The BA wants a window that

has a close button
has a maximize button
has no enabled minimize button

He wants us, Java devs, to achieve what the C guys did which is this

Considering the requirements for window control buttons, it seems there's no way around JFrame. But how do I disable the minimize button? I will consider going for native methods, if it's the only way (the apps are installed on Windows PCs)
I can do something like this, but the minimize button stays enabled -- just the frame pops back up
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class NonMinimizableFrameDemo {

    public NonMinimizableFrameDemo() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.addWindowListener(getWindowAdapter());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(NonMinimizableFrameDemo::new);
    }
    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    private WindowAdapter getWindowAdapter() {
        return new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent we) {
                frame.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Cant Minimize");
            }
        };
    }
}


You can use an undecorated JFrame with a custom title bar.  You can also switch from Java to a more suitable Windows GUI language.  Whatever the customer is willing to pay for.

@GilbertLeBlanc can you show a small demo of a JFrame with a custom title bar?

Customizing JFrame Title Bar in Java: Removing Default One

@GilbertLeBlanc oh, you mean disabling the header and replacing it with a panel with JButtons. I'm sorry, it's not going to be accepted. I mean regular, ordinary window control buttons

You can draw shapes on a JPanel.  You can identify mouse clicks on specific locations of a JPanel.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the Performing Custom Painting section.

What is a "BA"? Avoid non-useful irrelevant abbreviations.

@BasilBourque Isn't it common enough to require no explanation? Aren't all software teams have BAs (people who translate business requirements into specific tasks for devs)?

Define every abbreviation on first use. (Or link to dictionary/encyclopedia.)

A complicated option is to undecorate the JFrame and put an JInternalFrame inside. With a listener you have to maximize the parent JFrame when the JInternalFrame is maximized.

package fenster;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameAdapter;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class Test
{
   public Test()
   {
      initComponents();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
      {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            new Test();
         }
      });
   }

   private JFrame frame;

   private void initComponents()
   {
      try
      {
         
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
      }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
        | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
      {
         // nothing
      }
  
      frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setUndecorated(true);
      frame.setResizable(true);
      frame.setSize(600, 400);
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      JInternalFrame iframe = new JInternalFrame();
      iframe.setResizable(true);
      iframe.setClosable(true);
      iframe.setMaximizable(true);
      iframe.setIconifiable(false);   
      iframe.setSize(600, 400);
      iframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
      iframe.addInternalFrameListener(getAdapter());
      iframe.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyPropertyChangeListener());
      iframe.addMouseMotionListener( new DragHandler() );
      frame.addMouseMotionListener( new DragHandler() );
      frame.add(iframe);
      iframe.setVisible(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   private InternalFrameAdapter getAdapter()
   {
       return new InternalFrameAdapter()
       {
          @Override
          public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e)
          {
             System.exit(0);
          }
       };
    }

   private class MyPropertyChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener
   {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
      {
         dealWithEvent(evt);   
      }
   }

   private class DragHandler extends MouseInputAdapter
   {
       public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent evt )
       {
          dealWithEvent(evt);
       }
   }

   private void dealWithEvent (EventObject event)
   {      
      if(event instanceof PropertyChangeEvent)
      {
         PropertyChangeEvent e = (PropertyChangeEvent) event;
         if(e.getPropertyName().equalsIgnoreCase("maximum"))
         {
            if(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width == frame.getWidth())
            {
               frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
            }
            else
            {
               frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            }
         }
      }
      else if(event instanceof MouseEvent && ((MouseEvent) event).getY() < 200)
      {
         MouseEvent e = (MouseEvent) event;
         int x = e.getX();
         int y = e.getY();
         int screenX = frame.getX();
         int screenY = frame.getY();
         screenX += x;
         screenY += y;
         frame.setLocation( screenX, screenY );
      }
      else if(event instanceof MouseEvent && ((MouseEvent) event).getY() > 200)
      {
         MouseEvent e = (MouseEvent) event;
         frame.setSize(e.getX(), e.getY());
      }  
   }
}


Thank you! Though it won't maximize to the extent of the screen (only to the extent of its parent)

That is why with a listener I maximize the parent when the internal frame is maximized.

Thank you for your input. It's likely to be the best possible way to do something like that in Swing

The minimize is disabled. Duplicate question: Disable JFrame minimize button
package fenster;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test
{
   public Test()
   {
      initComponents();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
      {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            new Test();
         }
      });
   }

   private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

   private void initComponents()
   {
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.addWindowListener(getWindowAdapter());
      frame.setSize(600, 400);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   private WindowAdapter getWindowAdapter()
  {
      return new WindowAdapter()
      {

         @Override
         public void windowIconified(WindowEvent we)
         {
            frame.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
         }
      };
   }
}


Thank you. I actually considered that and ran a small demo with a custom window adapter like yours. The problem is the button is still clickable, and the window is still minimized. It just pops back up right away

What about the other idea?
